# How do i stop the rails sever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pid

I run this command to start my server

```
rails s -b 10.x.x.x
```

then I got this error

```
[1013] * Puma version: 5.2.2 (ruby 2.6.3-p62) ("Fettisdagsbulle")
[1013] *  Min threads: 2
[1013] *  Max threads: 2
[1013] *  Environment: development
[1013] *   Master PID: 1013
[1013] *      Workers: 1
[1013] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
[1013] * Preloading application
Exiting

Address already in use - bind(2) for "10.x.x.x" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

How do I stop this current running server `10.x.x.x:3000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several utilities to get the PID of a proccess listening on a port.

```
lsof -i :3000
```

Will get you the PID and then you can kill it with `kill [PID]` or force it with `kill -9 [PID]`